# In spark, what does the parameter "minPartitions" works in SparkContext.textFile(path, minPartitions)?

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, either SparkContext or JavaSparkContext,
there is one parameter which is minPartitions when you call sc.textFile. what does this parameter imply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`minPartitions` will be passed to Hadoop's [`InputFormat.getSplits`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html#getSplits(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf%2C%20int)). The parameter is a *hint*, so you may get more or less partitions, depending on the Hadoop `InputFormat` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. so base on the InputFormat.getSplits, it says - "Logically split the set of input files for the job.
Each InputSplit is then assigned to an individual Mapper for processing.
Note: The split is a logical split of the inputs and the input files are not physically split into chunks. For e.g. a split could be <input-file-path, start, offset> tuple." so for Hdfs, when insert a file into the hdfs, the data being split into several data trunks and each will contain 64 MB size of data. then how would the mapper works?

Comment: for example I have a data file is 260 MB, so there will be 64MB, 64MB,64MB,64MB and 4MB. so let's say when I put the minPartitions for 3, then there will be 3 threads to read the file? if this is the case, then how they allocate the jobs in one node and multi-nodes for the 3 threads?

Comment: You're correct. I think for a 260 MB HDFS file you will get 5 splits, regardless of `minPartitions`. Spark creates one partition for each split. (RDDs are made up of partitions.) Then when you run a job on this RDD, one task will be created for each partition. Each worker node runs an executor. If an executor has N cores, it will pick up N tasks at a time and process them in parallel. When a task is finished, the executor picks up more tasks if there are any left.

Comment: appreciate the the Executor information, very helpful! so back the the minPartitions. so Spark will compare the minPartitions and num_data_trunk (the number of data trunks) for the given file, if minPartitons >=num_data_trunk, then number_of_splits = minPartitons, else number_of_splits = num_data_trunk. is that correct?  and in practice, how to pick the ideal number of minPartitons? is that associate with the number of cores? if yes then what is the formula, like minPartitons = c*number_of_cpus?

Comment: No, Spark just gives the `minPartitions` parameter to Hadoop's `InputFormat.getSplits`. If `getSplits` ignores it and returns a smaller or larger number of splits, then you will have a smaller or larger number of partitions. I don't actually know what the HDFS `InputFormat` does with this hint, sorry.

The recommendation for number of partitions is 3-4 times the total number of CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

minPartitions: Indicates the minimum number of partitions that make up the
RDD. The Spark engine can often determine the best number of partitions based
on the file size, but you may want to change the number of partitions for
performance reasons and, hence, the ability to specify the minimum number